# Angular2 routing : /users/new is handled as /users/:id

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I have 2 components : `UsersComponent` and `UserComponent`.

routing configuration is like this :

```
{ path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
{ path: 'users/:id', component: UserComponent }
```

which works fine. But when I add :

```
{ path: 'users/new', component: NewUserComponent }
```

it is handled by the 'users/:id' entry, so the `UserComponent` component is called.

How can I make 'users/new' to call the `NewUserComponent` component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply :

```
{ path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
{ path: 'users/new', component: NewUserComponent },
{ path: 'users/:id', component: UserComponent }
```

You just have to put the most "precise" path first.

Answer (score 1):

Change the places for them. Your routes are read sequentially and if a matched route is found, it works. So every call like `users/new` is considered `users/` with `id` set to `new`.

```
{ path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
{ path: 'users/new', component: NewUserComponent },
{ path: 'users/:id', component: UserComponent }
```

Comment: @Enima beat you by a minute :) Thanks for the quick response !